# Insert variable in $(#var).val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to insert a variable in `$(#var).val()` ?
In `<td>`, variable td should be used with # inside `$(#td).val()`

```js
$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(){ 
  var td = $(this).data("name");
  var formdata = {foodtypename: $(#add-food-type).val()}
   
  $.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    url: '/editItem/'+$(this).data("id"),
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var product = '<tr class="item'+data.id+'">
        <td id="'+data.id+'">'+$(#td).val()+'</td></tr>'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: your variable is called td and not #td

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you want to use `td` as `id` you could use concatenation sign  `+` :

```
$("#"+td).val()
```

Line should looks like :

```
var product='<tr class="item'+data.id+'"><td id="'+data.id+'">'+$("#"+td).val()+'</td></tr>';
```

**NOTE :** You're missing quotes in `$(#add-food-type).val()`, full code will be like :

```
$(document).on('click', '#edit', function(){    
  var td = $(this).data("name");
  var formdata = {foodtypename: $("#add-food-type").val()}

  $.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    url: '/editItem/'+$(this).data("id"),
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      var product = '<tr class="item'+data.id+'"><td id="'+data.id+'">'+$("#"+td).val()+'</td></tr>'
    }
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can't just insert a newline in the middle of a string if not using template literals or escaping the newline.

Comment: I've just missed that you could see that the same line in the explanation isn't separed.. (thanks updated my post)

Comment: I still don't see an answer (or question for that matter) explaining how to combine strings as useful to the users of SO. at least not in this format.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, I haven't finished writing the whole code. Will let know if it worked. and yes I will not insert newline. Thanks

Comment: He want to form a jQuery selector with variable, that was the question @KevinB and my answer was just combine it as string using the `+` sign .. Not sure if this deserve a Downvote..